# upgrading from 50 amp service to 100 amp service to a new box . Can I run 50 amp breaker out of it to supply my old box like it was originally?

Tags: electrical-panel

Upgrading my current 50 amp service to 100 amp service.  Can I now put my 100 amp service into this new panel and run a 50 amp double breaker to supply my old breaker panel?

Comment: What you're essentially asking is if you can use the existing panel as a sub-panel under the new service. It will depend on if your existing panel meets or can be readily configured to meet current code. Rather than trying to describe, can you shut the power off and take some photos with the panel open and wiring exposed? Then perhaps someone can offer a better opinion.

Comment: Where on this 3rd rock from the sun are you? Local codes matter. I categorize electrical work into 3 categories  1) Not safe, not code legal, 2) safe, but not code legal, and 3) safe and code legal.   This isn't an answer because I don't know enough about your current panel, but, with some re-wiring in what will become a sub-panel, you can probably do what you want.  In my neck of the woods, it means isolating the neutral from the ground and running a 4 wire connection (2 hots, a neutral and a ground) to the sub from the new panel.  Check local codes.

Comment: It should be possible, but there are a few older make of panels that should never have been made and are dangerous enough that they belong in the garbage.  Without knowing what you have and who your local overlords are, we cannot give a good answer except for maybe.

Comment: Can you post photos of the label on the inside of the existing panel's door please?

Comment: I agree with George without knowing what version of code your jurisdiction uses and any exceptions to the code for upgrades we could actually say both no and yes. Since it is a larger service some jurisdictions require modern code to be met as in AFCI’s & GFCI’s where the old panel usually can’t be updated, I put “gutters” I an electrical wireway to make splices or use the old panel in some cases, some jurisdictions do not require all the updates because 100a is the minimum panel size allowed today so where are you?

Comment: Once you have this all figured talk to your local inspector, he has the final say and if you are told it is OK it should pass without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

There are some definite "it depends" that we can't possibly guess:

- Really bad panel types that should be replaced ASAP (Federal Pacific, etc.). For safety reasons, best to move all the circuits straight to the new panel.
- Local codes: If you have to put GFCI and/or AFCI on circuits as part of the heavy-up (some places require that, some do not) then unless your old panel is in good shape and has modern GFCI and AFCI breakers (especially AFCI, as GFCI can usually be done at the receptacles just as effectively) available, then it makes more sense to move the circuits to the new panel and do everything there.

But the *big* gotcha is **ground/neutral mixing**. In a main panel, you can (essentially) mix grounds and neutrals because they are bonded in that panel. When you get the new panel, the bond will be there (unless it is actually put into an outside disconnect, but a lot of places don't require that yet). When that happens, you have to remove the bond from your old panel. If the old panel had grounds on a separate bar then that's easy. But if, as is often the case, a lot of grounds are going to the neutral bar, it may turn out to be quite a bit of work to get everything straightened out. *A picture of the old panel would help*.

Comment: Thank you gentelman , you all have valid points.  I was told by the owner of the mobile home park that the panal was a 100 amp capable.  But I will find out for sure by electrical contractor or otherwise.  I also was aware of the neatrul ground being isolated on the sub panal.  Thank you for your time and I will take some pictures of my existing panal so we can all have a look .  Thanks again.

Comment: @dino please take the [tour] to see the proper way to say "thanks".